# Mobile Specific Content Delivered by Media Queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website and I want it to show different content on desktops and mobile devices. Instead of just rearranging the desktop-based content for the mobile device, I want to include content specifically tailored (rewritten) for mobile devices. How can I deliver this mobile specific content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do this at the server level and have to use media queries then the best option would be to use classes for varying content blocks that are mobile / desktop only and hide / show them based on the media queries.